# add class to jquery ( find and replace text )

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have find and replace text jquery code which is totally working fine for me, i only want to add class to it so that i can do some css work,
my code below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//find and replace text jquery
jQuery(".element small").text(function(index, text) { 
return text.replace('Draft', 'Draft Demonatisation '); 
});
</script>
```

so now Draft is the text that will be replaced with Draft Demonatisation. I want to give class textbot to  Draft and textbite class to Demonatisation.
any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$(".element small").text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace('Draft', 'Draft Demonatisation ');
}).toggleClass(function(){
  var $class = "";
  $class += ($(this).text().indexOf('Draft') > -1 ? " textbot":"")
  $class += ($(this).text().indexOf('Demonatisation') > -1 ? " textbite":"")
  return $class;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".element small").text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace('Draft', 'Draft Demonatisation ');
}).toggleClass(function(){
  var $class = "";
  $class += ($(this).text().indexOf('Draft') > -1 ? " textbot":"")
  $class += ($(this).text().indexOf('Demonatisation') > -1 ? " textbite":"")
  return $class;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">
<small>Draft</small>
</div>
```